# Word Press and database from another server sync

Tags: mysql

I have a problem, i'm new in this, so can someone explain to me can WordPress site on one server read database from another server? And how to do it if is possible? I have WordPress site on one server that is Woocommerce store, and i want to prices and details of product read from another database that is used on another server (which is in my real physical store, so i want when i change price in program in my real store, automatically change on my WP website). So, some people tell me that It may be easier if i regularly push the products master data onto my wordpress server in one way or another and import it into its mysql database. If there is a way, and there certainly is, how data can be entered in my wp database, or is there kind of a service or cron can be created that will automatically enter data into my site database every 5 minutes or something like that?

Comment: What's your master system? Does it have change hooks you could use to call the WooCommerce REST API to update it whenever the master system changes?

Comment: But yes, you can write a cron job inside or outside WordPress to connect to the other database and make updates. In WordPress you can make any database connection you want using whatever libraries are available to PHP. I wouldn't move the master database into WooCommerce, no.